# /var/run/reboot-required not set after unattended kernel update

Tags: apt, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I've set up unattended-upgrade on an Ubuntu 14.04.1 server. It has installed the kernel .41 over .40 yesterday at 4:10. Automatic reboot is configured for 3:00, so it should have rebooted last night. But it didn't.

Today, it installed another kernel version .43. Still the /var/run/reboot-required file does not exist, and the mail from unattended-upgrade doesn't contain any notice of a required reboot. So I don't expect the scheduled reboot to work tomorrow and the new kernel still won't be applied.

What's the issue here? Why doesn't that work as configured?

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "03:00";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `update-notifier-common` installed? According to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package) you need it for automatic reboots to work.

Comment: Didn't have it installed. Now I have, but I'm still waiting for updates that require a reboot. Can't verify the success until then.