# Installation of new kernel does not write to /var/run/reboot-required on Intel x64 system (but works on RasPi)

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, reboot

I have Ubuntu Server 22.04 installed on both an Intel Atom (amd64) and a Raspberry Pi (arm64).

With the last kernel update (installed by `unattended-upgrades`) the files `/var/run/reboot-required` and `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` have not been created on the Intel system (and thus the system is not flagged for reboot), but on the RasPi this works as expected.

**Log entries** from `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

*Intel Atom:*

```
Start-Date: 2022-05-24  06:52:55
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-5.15.0-33-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-33.34, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-33-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-33.34, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-33-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-33.34, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-33:amd64 (5.15.0-33.34, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-33-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-33.34, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.30.33, 5.15.0.33.36), linux-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.30.33, 5.15.0.33.36), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.30.33, 5.15.0.33.36)
End-Date: 2022-05-24  06:53:41

Start-Date: 2022-05-24  06:53:46
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-27.28)
End-Date: 2022-05-24  06:53:47

Start-Date: 2022-05-24  06:53:51
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-27.28), linux-image-5.15.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-27.28), linux-modules-5.15.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-27.28)
End-Date: 2022-05-24  06:53:56

Start-Date: 2022-05-24  06:54:00
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-27:amd64 (5.15.0-27.28)
End-Date: 2022-05-24  06:54:02
```

*Raspberry Pi:*

```
Start-Date: 2022-05-25  06:44:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-5.15.0-1008-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0-1008.8, automatic), linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1008:arm64 (5.15.0-1008.8, automatic), linux-image-5.15.0-1008-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0-1008.8, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0-1008.8, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0.1006.6, 5.15.0.1008.8), linux-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0.1006.6, 5.15.0.1008.8), linux-image-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0.1006.6, 5.15.0.1008.8)
End-Date: 2022-05-25  06:46:44

Start-Date: 2022-05-25  06:47:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-5.15.0-1005-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0-1005.5), linux-image-5.15.0-1005-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0-1005.5)
End-Date: 2022-05-25  06:47:20

Start-Date: 2022-05-25  06:47:26
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-raspi:arm64 (5.15.0-1005.5)
End-Date: 2022-05-25  06:47:29

Start-Date: 2022-05-25  06:47:35
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-raspi-headers-5.15.0-1005:arm64 (5.15.0-1005.5)
End-Date: 2022-05-25  06:47:42
```

**Kernel history** (5.15 kernel line): `dpkg --list *linux-image* | grep "\-5.15" | grep -v "un"`

*Intel Atom:* (now has kernel 5.15.0-30 and 5.15.0-33 installed)

```
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-27-generic          5.15.0-27.28  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic          5.15.0-30.31  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-33-generic          5.15.0-33.34  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

*Raspberry Pi:* (now has kernel 5.15.0-1006 and 5.15.0-1008 installed)

```
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1005-raspi          5.15.0-1005.5 arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.0 on ARMv8 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1006-raspi          5.15.0-1006.6 arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.0 on ARMv8 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1008-raspi          5.15.0-1008.8 arm64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.0 on ARMv8 SMP
```

**Cat of files** `/var/run/reboot-required` and `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`.

*Intel Atom:*

```
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required
cat: /var/run/reboot-required: No such file or directory

$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
cat: /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs: No such file or directory
```

*Raspberry Pi:*

```
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required
*** System restart required ***

$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
linux-image-5.15.0-1008-raspi
linux-base
```

I already read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560539/var-run-reboot-required-not-set-after-unattended-kernel-update), but I have the package `update-notifier-common` installed on both systems. And yes, the symlink `/run -> /var/run` also exist.

Both systems have been upgraded from 20.04, and here it worked as expected on both systems. It should also be noted that for other packages (like `libssl3`), I'm pretty sure the `/var/run/reboot-required` was updated on both systems.

This is a little annoying for me because I use these files, both to be aware that a kernel update has been installed, and also to trigger a manual reboot at a designated time. So any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this and get the `/var/run/reboot-required` files to be written will be much appreciated.

*NB: I just got confirmation from a friend (also with an Intel server), and here the files have been written as expected. So it seems it's not a package bug either.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for now, my solution is running the following script each day with `cron` to mimic the desired behavior of `apt`/`unattended-upgrade`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get last reboot time and installed kernel
lastreboot=$(date -r /home/am/last_reboot +%s)
kernelinst=$(grep 'Upgrade: linux-headers-generic' /var/log/apt/history.log -A 1 -B 1 | tail -n 3)

# Get kernel version and install date
if [[ -n "$kernelinst" ]]
then
  kernelvers=$(echo "$kernelinst" | grep -oP 'linux-image-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9-]+[A-Z-a-z]+')
  kerneldate=$(date -d $(echo "$kernelinst" | grep 'End-Date' | awk '{print $2}') +%s)
fi

# Check if reboot-required.pkgs is already updated
if [[ -f /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs ]]
then
  kernelpkgs=$(grep "$kernelvers" /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs)
fi

# Write to reboot-required/reboot-required.pkgs if conditions are met
if [[ "$kerneldate" -gt "$lastreboot" ]] && [[ "$kernelvers" != "$kernelpkgs" ]]
then
  # Echo to /var/run/reboot-required
  echo "*** System restart required ***" | tee /var/run/reboot-required
  # Echo to /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
  echo "$kernelvers" | tee -a /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
  echo "linux-base" | tee -a /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
else
  echo "Do nothing"
fi
```